# Is there a diff between a,b = await get_a(), await get_b() vs separately declaring them?

Tags: python, multithreading, async-await, concurrency, parallel-processing

If I do this, do the awaits actually happen concurrently? I was under the impression I need to do something like `asyncio.gather` to make it work, but came across this code and was wondering if this is a shortcut.

```
a,b = await get_a(), await get_b()
```

or is this exactly the same as

```
a = await get_a()
b = await get_b()
```

Answer (score 0):

It's basically the same as the two-line version. The only difference is that both awaitables are awaited before `a` is assigned. `get_a` and `get_b` do not run concurrently.